# Why can't C++ compiler know a pointer is pointing to a derived class?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, compiler-construction

I've just started learning about OOP in C++. I was wondering why is the virtual keyword needed to instruct the compiler to do late binding ? Why can't the compiler know at compile time that the pointer is pointing to a derived class ?

```
class A { 
    public: int f() { return 'A';}
};

class B : public A {
    public: int f() { return 'B';}
};

int main() {

    A* pa;
    B b;
    pa = &b; 
    cout << pa->f() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show a minimal code example that demonstrates your question?

Comment: Because that's the way C++ is designed - specifically the "don't pay for what you don't use" philosophy.    Resolving a call of a base class function to a derived class overload at run time costs more than statically resolving to the base class version, so it is not the default choice (i.e. it is necessary to deliberately make a function virtual, rather than all functions being virtual by default).    There are other reasons too.

Comment: @CoryKramer I've added an example. In this case, isn't it clear that pa is pointing to an object of class B ? Thanks for your quick reply !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I started out with some comments on an answer, but decided I should just write up my own answer.)

I've rearranged your code slightly here to make it easier to compile and view the output:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#ifdef V
#define VIRTUAL virtual
#else
#define VIRTUAL /*nothing*/
#endif

class A { 
    public: VIRTUAL char f() { return 'A';}
};

class B : public A {
    public: char f() { return 'B';}
};

int main() {
    A* pa;
    B b;
    pa = &b; 
    std::cout << pa->f() << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling and running it shows:

```
$ c++ t.cc && ./a.out
A
$ c++ -DV t.cc && ./a.out
B
```

which shows that the `virtual` keyword changes the behavior of the program.  This is in fact *required* by the language standard.  Your question could, I think, be best rephrased as *Why is the standard written this way* (which has a more useful general answer) rather than *Can the compiler optimize my code* (which has a specific but useless answer: yes, it can, but it's still required to print `A`, not `B`).

The language definition doesn't *forbid* the compiler from doing special optimization tricks.  Instead—and especially so in this case, for C++— the language specification specifically tries to make it *easier* for compiler-writers to optimize.  This winds up putting more of a burden on C++ *programmers*.

#### If C++ were a different language ...

The feature you're talking about, which is the `virtual` keyword, specifically exists because of this.  The language *could* have been defined differently (and some other languages are): they could have said that compiler writers *must not* ever assume that, given some valid `A* pa`, `pa` points to some actual instance of type `A`.  Then:

```
std::cout << pa->f() << std::endl;
```

would always have to figure out: *What is the real underlying type of `*pa` and hence what function `f` shall I call here?*

In this hypothetical (not-C++) language,<sup>1</sup> a compiler that optimizes *could* take your code and build it to call `B::f()` directly, because `pa` points to an instance of type `B`.  But in this same language, a compiler that tries to optimize heavily *could not* make assumptions about functions where the underlying type of `pa` is determined by something not predictable at compile-time:

```cpp
void f(A* pa) {
    std::cout << pa->f() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    A a;
    B b;
    f(argc > 1 ? &b : &a);
}
```

This program needs to print `A` when called with no extra arguments, and `B` when called with extra arguments.  So if our not-C++ language *lacks* a `virtual` keyword, or defines it as a no-op, function `f`—which calls either `A::f()` or `B::f()` at run-time—must *always* figure out which underlying function to call.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's not C either.  The name D is taken.  Perhaps P, from the BCPL progression?

---

#### Conclusion

Because C++ *does* have the `virtual` keyword, the variant we build that has a non-virtual `f()` in base class `A` can optimize `pa->f()` calls by *assuming* that `pa->f()` calls `A::f()`.  Hence, instead of actually calling `A::f()`, an optimizing compiler can just write `"A\n"` to `std::cout`.  Whether or not the C++ compiler optimizes, the call *must* produce `A` rather than `B`.

The variant with the `virtual` keyword inserted *must not* assume that `pa->f()` calls `A::f()`.  If it can optimize enough to see that `pa->f()` calls `B::f()`, and therefore, at compile time, eliminate the call entirely and have the function write `"B\n"`, that's OK!  If it *can't* optimize that much, that's OK too—at least, as far as the language specification goes.

You, as a programmer, are required to know this about the `virtual` keyword, and to use it whenever you want the *compiler* to be *forced* to pick the right function based on the actual runtime class, whether or not the compiler is smart enough to do that at compile-time.  If you want to *allow and force* the compiler to just use the base-class function every time, you can omit the `virtual` keyword.

Comment: Your answer is the best, thank you so much for your help !! I would upvote but I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding not knowing at compile time, it is often the case the behavior is only known at runtime. Consider this example

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {};
struct B : A {};
struct C : A {};

int main()
{
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    A* a = x == 1 ? new B : new C;
}
```

In this example, how could the compiler know if `a` will point to a `B*` or `C*`? It cannot because the behavior is dependent on runtime values.

Comment: But what if the new keyword is not in use ? As in the example I gave ?

Comment: @VeryConfused: you asked a general-case question, or at least, everyone who answered assumed you meant the general-case. Given a very specific case, compilers *are* allowed to *optimize* based on the language's rules, so given your source, since the compiler can prove that `*pa` *is* `b`, it can optimize some things away.

Comment: Knowing that `*pa` *is* `b`, however, doesn't give the compiler license to call `B::f`: the language rules require that it call `A::f`, so it does, *whether or not it did this kind of optimization*. Adding `virtual` to the definition in class `A` changes this rule: now the compiler *must* call `B::f` instead.

Comment: If we have the more general case—where the underlying type of `*pa` is not known, and maybe not even know-*able*, for whatever reason—the `virtual` keyword, or lack thereof, gives the compiler the option to assume that `*pa` has type `A` (when `virtual` is missing) or not make any such assumption (when `virtual` is present in the base class definition).

Answer (score 5):

How could it (in full generality)? For example

```
#include <cstdlib>
struct Parent {};
struct Child : Parent {};

int main()
{
    Parent* p = std::rand() % 2 ? new Parent() : new Child();
}
```

Comment: Ok are you saying that pointer pa in my example could be pointing to a dynamically created object (even though it is not) so thats why the compiler doesn't call the override?

Comment: @VeryConfused: What I'm saying is that the compiler cannot possibly know at compile time what `p` is pointing to.

Answer (score 5):

Lets say you have a simple class-hierarchy like

```
class Animal
{
    // Generic animal attributes and properties
};

class Mammal : public Animal
{
    // Attributes and properties specific to mammals
};

class Fish : public Animal
{
    // Attributes and properties specific to fishes
};

class Cat : public Mammal
{
    // Attributes and properties specific to cats
};

class Shark : public Fish
{
    // Attributes and properties specific to sharks
};

class Hammerhead : public Shark
{
    // Attributes and properties specific to hammerhead sharks
};
```

<sub>[A little long-winded, but I want to have the "concrete" classes to be far away from each other]</sub>

Now lets say we have a function like

```
void do_something_with_animals(Animal* animal);
```

And finally let's call this function:

```
Fish *my_fish = new Hammerhead;
Mammal* my_cat = new Cat;

do_something_with_animals(my_fish);
do_something_with_animals(my_cat);
```

Now if we think a little, in the `do_something_with_animals` function there is really no way of knowing *exactly* what the argument `animal` might point to. Is it a `Mammal`? A `Fish`? A specific `Fish` sub-type?

This is even harder for the compiler if the `do_something_with_animals` function is defined in a different [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), where the definition of the `Mammal` and `Fish` classes (or any of its sub-classes) might not even be available.

Answer (score 2):

The virtual keyword marks individual functions as late-bound. This isn't about what the compiler can or cannot know about any pointers to the object. It's about communicating programmer intent ("this function is meant to be overridden") and efficiency ("this function needs the late-binding mechanism enabled").