# Why is late binding needed in this example?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, binding, compiler-construction

I understand why the virtual keyword is needed for overriding when objects of subclasses are dynamically created but, in the following example, why is late binding needed (virtual keyword) to override? Can't the compiler tell at compile time that pa is pointing to a derived class?

```
class A { 
    public: int f() { return 'A';}
};

class B : public A {
    public: int f() { return 'B';} 
};

int main() {

    //I understand this case, since pa is pointing to 
    //something created at runtime, virtual keyword is needed
    //to return 66 
    A* pa;
    pa = new B;
    cout << pa->f() << endl; //returns 65 

    //But why in this case where b2 is created during 
    //compile time, compiler doesn't know pa is pointing
    //to a derived class? 
    B b2; 
    pa = &b2; 
    cout << pa->f() << endl; //returns 65
}
```

Comment: `B b2;` is not created at compile time.

Comment: You need to understand mechanism of virtual call. pa is of type A * not B* so by default it will call A's version of f. With virtual key word, new information get stored in terms of vtable where call to actual function is resolved

Comment: Consider `bool use_b; std::cin >> use_b; pa = use_b ? &b2 : new A;`.

Comment: @shanker861 ok but vtable is created during compile time right ? then why is the pa pointing to b2 not calling the right f() ?

Comment: @George are you suggesting that the compiler isn't calling b2's f() because in general pa could be pointing to something dynamically created ?

Comment: @VeryConfused The compiler itself doesn't call anything (in your program). I was more suggesting that the compiler can't know in every scenario what `pa` would be pointing at, and creating some crazy rule that says if the compiler can figure it out then it invokes the deepest child function is... ridiculous. Whether or not something is created dynamically is really irrelevant.

Comment: @S.M. could you explain more ? Ive always been taught automatic variables are created during compilation.

Comment: @George Ok but unless something involves user input (cin) or dynamically created objects, why can't the compiler figure out what `pa` is pointing to ?

Comment: Now pass `pa` to a function in another translation unit. Even if we _wanted_ things to work the way you describe (which we don't), they cannot except in the most simple and contrived cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question really does not revolve around whether the compiler can "know" or not the precise type of object `pa` refers to. It revolves around the semantics of C++.

When you declare a method `f`, you are telling the compiler how you want a call to `f` to be handled. In the case that `A::f` is not declared `virtual`, you are saying that if `pa->f()` is called and `pa` has the declared type of `A*`, you want the compiler to use the definition in `A::f`. Certainly, `*pa` is an object of type `A`, even though it might also be an object of some derived type of `A`.

If, on the other hand, you declare `f` to be `virtual`, you are telling the compiler that you want it refer to the most derived type of the object currently pointed to by `pa`, and use the definition of `f` from that type (or its appropriate supertype).

The semantics of C++ need to be deterministic. That is, you as the programmer need to be able to predict which definition of `f` will be used in any given circumstance. If you think about it, it would be really difficult to program in a language with a rule which states "use `B::f` if you happen to be able to figure out that `pa` points to an object of type `B`, but use `A::f` if you are not sure what `pa` points to". How hard should the compiler try to figure out what `pa` points to? If in the future, someone in the compiler team figures out how to make a more accurate determination, should the semantics of your program magically change? Would you be happy with that?

Note that it is actually quite possible in both of the snippets you present that the compiler *can* figure out what the type of the object pointed to by `pa` is. So even if `f` were `virtual`, an optimising compiler could well omit the code to look up the correct method in the vtable, and just call the correct method directly. Nothing in the C++ standard prohibits such an optimisation, and I believe that it is quite common. So if in the future someone in the compiler team figures out a better way of determining the type of a variable, it will not change the semantics of your program -- it will still invoke the same method. But it might result in your program invoking your method more quickly. That is an outcome which is much more likely to make the future you happy.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer !! I wish I could upvote but I dont have enough rep

Answer (score 1):

This all resolves around the fact that C++ is a statically typed language.  Thus, `pa` is treated by the compiler as a pointer to an `A`, not a pointer to a `B` (because you declared it as such), and it follows that if you call `pa->f()` it will call `A::f()` rather than `B::f()` unless `f()` is declared virtual.

In fact, that's the whole point of virtual methods - to dispatch to the correct method when you call the method through a polymorphic pointer.

Comment: Ok but what the virtual keyword does is tell the compiler to delay binding until runtime right ? Why should binding be delayed until runtime ?

Comment: Because the compiler doesn't know that `pa` is actually pointing to an object of type `B`.  That information is lost at compile time.  Calling a `virtual` method goes through an extra level of indirection (the vtable) to dispatch to the right method.

Comment: Isn't the vtable created at compile time ?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't change the type of `pa`.

Comment: Why can't the vtable be used during compile time if it was already created then?

Comment: Could the language have been made that way? Sure, maybe. But it wasn't. And we don't need or want it to be. @VeryConfused your argument seems to hinge on "why _can't_ the compiler do it?", which is not the same as "why _doesn't_ the compiler do it?". Just because we _can_ do something, doesn't always mean we _should_.

Answer (score 0):

In the very simple example you show, yes the compiler can trivially discover that `pa` is a pointer to an object whose dynamic type is `B`.

But, in order to use that information in the way you describe, several things would have to be true:

1. The rules for how pointers work would have to *require* this information, in all cases
2. This information would have to be available in more than just a simple/contrived example (it isn't — pass `pa` to a function in another translation unit, and suddenly the compiler run processing that unit has no idea what the dynamic type is; some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61955010/4386278) were given when you asked this question before, three hours ago)
3. We, as programmers, would generally *want* this behaviour (we don't — we can opt in with `virtual` if we like but otherwise we want nice simple behaviour where the type of an expression defines what the expression means and what the operands do).

Finally, note that your description of dynamic *vs* automatic storage duration / allocation methods as "runtime" vs "compile-time" is not quite accurate, though these terms get quite wooly anyway given how many different layers of abstraction are involved in building and running a C++ program.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer !! I understand now what went wrong in my thinking. Could you expand abut on your final point about dynamic vs automatic variables ?